# How to enable various Fiddler's settings by default?

Tags: default-settings, fiddler

When launching Fidder, various options are always disabled.

How can these option be enabled by default?

For example, "Disable Caching":

[image: The Disable Caching option]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by going to Rules=>Customize Rules and changing the various `RulesOption`.

Each of these options look like:

```
    public static RulesOption("[Name of option on menu]"[, "[Name of parent menu]"])
    var [option]: boolean = false;
```

For example:

```
    public static RulesOption("&Disable Caching", "Per&formance")
    var [option]: boolean = false;
```

Just change it to `true`:

**`var m_DisableCaching: boolean = true;`**

[image: Disable Caching by default]