# How to enable Automatic Breakpoints by default?

Tags: default-settings, fiddler

When launching Fiddler "Automatic" Breakpoints are always set to "Disabled".

Unlike [How to enable various Fiddler's settings by default?](https://superuser.com/questions/1512962/how-to-enable-various-fiddlers-settings-by-default), this isn't a boolean choice so there isn't a related true/false `RulesOption` in Rules=>Customize Rules.

So how can they be enabled to be either "Before Responses" or "After Responses by default?

[image: Automatic Breakpoints]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can click Rules=>Customize Rules and add this code:

```
 static function OnBoot() {
            FiddlerApplication.Prefs.SetBoolPref("fiddler.ui.ephemeral.rules.breakonresponse", true);
            // or
            // FiddlerApplication.Prefs.SetBoolPref("fiddler.ui.ephemeral.rules.breakonrequest", true);
```